# Add simple stock to configurable product collection

Tags: mysql, product-collection, stock

The  `Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')`  didn't calculate stock for configurable products.

I think, with MySQL, there is a way, to calculate configurable product stock from simple products stock.

- simple product = 1 cataloginventory_stock_item
- configurable product = 2 or more cataloginventory_stock_item

Can someone help us to create a SQL query to do this?

Comment: you need to assign associated products qty to configurable product

Answer (score 1):

Try it the magento way,

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(874); // 874 is the product_id of configurable product

$config = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')
        ->setProduct($product);

$collection = $config->getUsedProductCollection()
                     ->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFilterByRequiredOptions();

$total_qty = 0;
foreach ($collection as $sprod) {
     //$sprod = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($sprod->getId());
     $qty = intval(Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($sprod)->getQty());
     $total_qty+=$qty;
}
echo $total_qty;
```

Comment: Have a look at `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Status::addStockStatusToProducts`. It would be a magento way of adding the stock item to each product in your collection.